# why Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>' in swift 4?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a `CGMutablePath()` such as:

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
CGPathAddRect(path, nil, playableRect)
```

The compiler keeps on giving me the following error:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type
>   'UnsafePointer'

I can't seem to find any info on this matter online. I've tried converting the `Int` to `CGFloat` but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: What is `playableRect`?

Comment: You should probably use [`addRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgmutablepath/2427119-addrect) instead of [`CGPathAddRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1411144-cgpathaddrect)

Answer (score 4):

A major problem with your code is that `CGPathAddRect` is not valid in any recent version of Swift. You should update your Xcode to something like Xcode 9.2 and write your code in a modern Swift like Swift 4.

You will then be able to write:

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addRect(playableRect)
```

...and things will be much simpler and clearer for you.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. The issue is that I started this game back in 2.0

Comment: Understood, but not to migrate forward just puts you out of touch with everyone else. I couldn't even test your code, because I don't have a version of Swift old enough!